# Recomiple the binary or the derived classes for adding new method in base class

Tags: c++, virtual, abi

Some similar questions are posted before but I couldn't see the answer for my specific requirement.

I have a base class which is compiled into a shared library(.so). This library is been used and there are some classes derived from my base and using the virtual functions of my base class.

Now I need to modify my base class to add a new method(NON-VIRTUAL) which will be internally used. I will then recompile the shared library.

Does the derived classes needs to be recompiled? 
Does the binary created using the derived classes and the shared library needs to be recompiled?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you will not need to recompile the derived classes. Recompilation is only required if the knowledge of binary structure of the class obtained from the header file (used in the derived classes) is changed. This happens is

- A data member is added
- A modification is made to the Vtable (change in virtual functions)
- A modification is made to an existing function signature
- Changes to inline functions

Since neither is occurring here, you should be fine. 
Referenced [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033487/c-when-recompilation-is-required)

Comment: There is no need of a recompilation if a new method is added. Thanks Smeeheey.