# Mandatory class recompilation when dependency changes

Tags: java, c++, oop, interface, solid-principles

Context:

I'm java programmer and reading Uncle Bob Agile Software Development. Regarding ISP Interface Segregation Principle there is given an argument which I understand as:

Lets have:

```
interface Service {
  function doA();
}
class ServiceImpl implements Service {...}
class ServiceClient {
  // ServiceImpl is injected; eg either through constructor or setter
  private Service service;
  function useOnlyDoA() {
    service.doA();
  }
}
```

And now, if interface Service changes, e.g. method `doB()` is added, then all dependent classes e.g. `ServiceClient` have to be recompiled, even if they don't use added method! (really??)

1. Is it true for java?
2. Is it true for c++?
3. For which other languages it it true, and for which isn't?

I lived in conviction that regarding java if `ServiceClient` is in package e.g. `client.jar`, interface `Service` in `service.jar` and `ServiceImpl` in `impl.jar`, then `client.jar` doesn't have to be recompiled and rebuild if it doesn't use new methods from Service interface and it can be used together with new versions of `service.jar` and `impl.jar`. It seems to me that things go this way in java.
Is it other in eg c++ or some other languages?

Possibly in c++ much more is broken, eg
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4033900/1423685

To make it clear:

I'm not asking about recompiling class implementing changed interface (this is obvious, it class has to implement new added method).
But I am asking if I have to recompile class ServiceClient which is using this interface even when class isn't using new added methods. Possibly in c++ BC changes and client really has to be recompiled, but it seems to me that not in java.

Edit:

I implemented a test in java. 4 jars:

- interface.jar - contains interface `public interface Service`
- implementation.jar - contains `public class ServiceImpl implements Service`
- two above jars change
- two below jars didn't change even when above changed
- interfaceclient.jar - dependant on interface.jar, contains class `ClientOfService` taking `Service` as a constructor parameter, uses this service in it's `doA()` method
- application.jar - dependant on all above jars. Class App in main method creates ServiceImpl instance and passes it as an arg to a constructor of ClientOfService, then cals a method on ClientOfService which makes a call to a method doA() from Service:
  `public static void main(String[] args) {
    Service service = new ServiceImpl();
    ClientOfService clientOfService = new ClientOfService(service);
    System.out.println("App.main() :: calling clientOfService.doWorkCallingDoAFromService");
    clientOfService.doWorkCallingDoAFromService();
    System.out.println("App.main() :: end of main");
  }`

The main in App run successfully after change of interface.jar and implementation.jar (I added some unused methods and removed one old method).

So the challenge is how to change interface (of course without changing `doA()` method declaration) and implementation to stop it running successfully? Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Note the ISP is about more than just recompilation. Unused interface methods may require transitive dependencies which the client does not otherwise need.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, if you change the interface, you need to recompile the classes that implement it in Java and in C++.  This has several reasons, among others:

- the Java compiler needs to check if the classes implementing the interface are still compliant (a class that implemetns the interface must implement all its methods).
- the C++ compiler might need to change the technical layout of the classes (e.g. `vtable` if doB() is virtual), and verify if another member function with the same signature but in another base class is not hidden by the newly created one.

The whole thing of the ISP is to avoid such situations. So if `doB()` has in reality nothing to do with this interface,  you'd better go for a segregated interface with just `doB()`, and change/recompile only the classes that need to implement it.

**Edit:** The same principle applies to classes that use the interface.  Some of the arguments may of course be implementation dependent:

- For C++, the code generated for the using class will need to rely on the right interface definition, so that it can make the right assumptions about the vtable layout and generate the right code.  This is why recompilation is also required for the using classes.
- For Java, the call to interface methods could indeed rely on explicit names and run-time resolution. I'm not a java specialist, so here a corrigendum: Some changes to the interface are in fact [allowed by the Java Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.5) without requiring recompilation.  But some changes require a recompilation.

Comment: I made edit with clarification. Let's say doA and doB have to be implemented by the same class. The question is if separating them to 2 different services changes something for the customer/client of Service which is not dependant on doB? Of course apart of that this is more readable, and not exposing doB to somebody that doesn't need it is good in itself, but this is not my doubt.

Comment: @bastiat I've edited to address your complementary question.  Hope this helps :-)

Comment: @bastiat I've added some remarks to my answer following your second edit.

Answer (score 0):

> For which other languages it it true, and for which isn't?

This is really implementation-specific characteristic rather than language characteristic.

Recompilation is usually needed for language implementations that compiles member access on interfaces to memory addresses or array indexes of a function table. This is how most static language compilers are implemented. Most Java and C implementations would fall under this category.

Recompilation wouldn't be necessary for languages implementation that compiles member access to dictionary lookup (so that it uses the function name for the lookup, rather than a substitute index). This is how most dynamic languages compilers are implemented. For example, most Python implementations don't need to recreate .pyc files if classes in another file changes its interface.

So the main divide is between static and dynamic language. There are exceptions of course. It's possible in some static language to ensure that any new additions are appended to the function table, so existing code that code that uses the old indexes will still work. For library authors in most static languages, it is an important consideration to only change interfaces in ways that preserves binary compatibility if the language implementation allows for it.

Comment: Thx for reply. Is java static or dynamic? Is c++ static or dynamic? In which ways can I change interface in java breaking binary compatibility?

Comment: C++ and Java are both static languages. Although JVM do have dynamic language features, but these aren't used much in Java itself, mostly used by other dynamic languages that runs on Java. Refer to [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html) for ways you can modify a Java program without breaking binary compatibility.